# I set up a configuration for each environment in the design phase. After I deploy, there are missing parameters. Why?

Tags: ssis

I'm using SSIS 2012. During development, I added Dev and Prod configuration to define different values for a few parameters found in `Project.params`.

However, when I deploy to the dev server then try to execute one of the project's deployed packages from within SSMS, it asks me to fill in some missing configuration. So somehow my configuration never made it to the deployed project.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Since I'm misunderstanding your question, could you try restating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I love this site. I'll bang my head on something for a while but as soon as I post my question here, I figure it out.

I misunderstood the behavior of the "Required" column on a parameter. [This post](http://www.katieandemil.com/ssis-2012-parameter-required-column-with-deployment) cleared it right up for me.